# Element type is invalid: expected a string / Check the render method of `Provider` error

Tags: redux, react-redux

I have the following code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import rootReducer from './redux/reducers/rootReducer';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import Main from './Main';

import './i18n';

const store = createStore(rootReducer,
    {},
    applyMiddleware(thunk));

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><BrowserRouter><Main/></BrowserRouter></Provider>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

But when I try to run it I get:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
>
> Check the render method of `Provider`.

My `Main` class looks like this:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        dashboard: state.dashboard
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
}

const Main = withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App));

export default Main;
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I was using `react-redux@6.0`. From the docs:
https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/releases/tag/v6.0.0

> Passing store as a prop to a connected component is no longer
>   supported. Instead, you may pass a custom context={MyContext} prop to
>   both  and . You may also pass {context :
>   MyContext} as an option to connect.

Anyways, downgrading to `5.1` solved it.

Comment: Thanks @Gambit2007, I am experiencing the same issue with v6, could anyone point me to some documentation about how to solve this issue without going back to v5??

Comment: Just to point out what my problem was, I had the same error because I was using a custom variable called context and passing it as a prop. The rendering also result in the same error. I finished changing the variable name.